# How to use button instead of anchor link in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following code before when I'm not using codeigniter:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()">
```

Now because I am using codeigniter I use this code to with the same functionality as above:

```
<?php echo anchor('bookings/remove/all', 'Clear Cart', array('onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure want to clear all bookings?')")); ?>
```

The first code will create a button. But the second code will create only link.

I'm new to codeigniter so please help me.

Thanks

Comment: It's not because you use codeigniter, that you are suppose to use the form or html library, you can leave the old html script.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use CI's function there is form helper available called `form_submit()`

```
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Clear Cart', 'onclick="clear_cart()"');
```

Don't forget to load form helper first though

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

there are loads other form helper functions available - check here - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

**Update**

In your javascript `clear_cart()` function add these lines at the begining -

```
function clear_cart() {
var result = confirm('Are you sure want to clear all bookings?');
if(!result) {
// cancel button 
return false;
}

.. rest of the code below here
```

Comment: hi, but how can i use the `Are you sure want to clear all bookings?`?

Comment: i need to call also this url: `bookings/remove/all`. I dont think it can be added in `clear_cart()` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo form_button('mysubmit', 'Clear Cart', 'onclick="clear_cart()"');
```